# How does Jetpack Compose handle drawable resources for different screen densities?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-imageview, screen-density, density-independent-pixel

I'm a total newbie with Jetpack Compose. I hope you may help shed some light on my issue.

In the old days, if you had a PNG drawable resource, you would provide multiple versions of that drawable depending on the target screen density - `mdpi` (1x), `hdpi` (1.5x), `xhdpi` (2x), `xxhdpi` (3x).

My question is regarding the case where you would be missing the drawable for one or more densities. Let's say, you would only provide the `mdpi` version of a drawable. Using the good old `ImageView`, running on an `xxhdpi` device, Android would scale the drawable 3x and render it correctly.

Now, the same does not seem to apply in Jetpack Compose. My specific case is this: I'm providing the `mdpi` and `xhdpi` versions of a drawable, but run the Compose app on an `xxhdpi` device. Compose does not scale the drawable to the `xxhdpi` size, but renders the `xhdpi` drawable (which appears smaller).

Is this the correct and expected behavior? What am I missing? Can you point me to some reading material which explains why this happens? Thanks in advance to all of you ;)